# Copy progress window missing when trying to copy in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, copy-paste

When I copy on my iMac using Finder in OS X 10.9.5, the popup window which shows the copy process and other related information (Speed, Files left, etc.) does not appear.

How can I restore this window again?  I've not found any option in the Finder or View menu.

Comment: Does it show if you try to move a file?

Comment: Does it show if you do click and hold on the finder icon in the Dock and select Show all windows

Answer (score 5):

As of macOS Monterey, in **Finder** > **Window** > **Show Progress Window**

Comment: Same exact issue here; apparently you can close or minimize the progress window now, and if you close it, it doesn't automatically reappear when you start a new copy!